# Why does the object not move to the coordinates?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I implemented a Circle class with properties:

- x - the initial value of the x coordinate
- y - the initial value of the y coordinate
- diameter - values of width and height
- color - fill color

Method: `draw()` - draws on the screen an element that is described by the specified properties.

Method: `move({x = 0, y = 0})` - moves the drawn object along the vector (x, y) - every time period (100ms) changes (adds \ subtracts) the coordinates by the value of x and y in accordance.

And the internal method `update()`, which changes the position of the drawn circle with the corresponding values of color, x, y of the object.

**Tell me why my circle does not move at the given coordinates with an interval of 1 second?**

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
        this.x = options.x;
        this.y = options.y;
        this.diameter = options.diameter;
        this.color = options.color;
    }

    draw() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        div.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
        div.style.width = `${this.diameter}px`;
        div.style.height = `${this.diameter}px`;
        div.style.border = "1px solid;";
        div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    move({x = 0, y = 0}) {
        let circle = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        setInterval(function moved() {
            circle.style.left = circle.offsetLeft + x + "px";
            circle.style.top = circle.offsetTop + y + "px";
        }, 1000)
    }
    _update() {
        this.x = x.move;
        this.y = y.move;
    }
}
let options = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    diameter: 100,
    color: 'red'
};
let circle = new Circle(options);
circle.draw();
circle.move({x: 200, y: 200});
```

Comment: You are setting the interval to `100` which is .1 seconds. And you are moving the circle by 1000 pixels, so it jumps out of view. When I change those, it works.

Comment: It is moving, your just drastically moving it every 0.1 second(s). Change your move call to something like `circle.move({x: 1, y: 1})` and you will see it moving more slowly so it doesn't immediately leave from the pages view.

Comment: corrected the coordinates and time, I want to see his move every second at the coordinates given by me, how to do it?

Comment: You are currently moving object for that distance indefinite time. You need to wrap it up a bit. Say you want to have linear transition, you should then do the interpolation between start and end points, and set how much time you want this animation to last. If you want to have 60 frames / second, you should set your interval to 16ms - that is one frame. So if your animation lasts 5 seconds, that is 300 frames, split coordinate X difference and coord Y diff with 300 frames, and you have a distance for each frame to move your object.

Comment: You're not using `_update` anywhere, but `x.move` and `y.move` don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an initial example ***(if I got, what you wanted)*** that you can use to get, what you want.

**Quick rundown:**

- The user sets the desired coordinates of the circle instance
- The duration of the animation can be changed via passing the `duration` option to the `move(...)` method e.g. `move({x: 100, y: 100, duration: 2500})`
- The circle will start a ticker with `setInterval` to reposition the circle
- The actual, in-between `x` and `y` coordinates will be calculated based on the progress of the given `duration`
- When the animation reaches its end, the `x` and `y` coordinates will be set to the initially given coordinates via `move(...)` and the whole moving of the circle is done

### Notes:

- **I know you didn't ask for animation**, but ***I dared to assume***, that this kind of demonstration will be more effective to help you to understand and/or get your results.
- I extracted the portion of your code, where you set the position of the circle to adhere to the [**DRY**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/what-are-dry-kiss-solid-etc-classified-as) principle.
- In order the code to be more demonstrable, I reduced the coordinates to lower values, but it will work with larger values too as well
- Animating **anything** with `setInterval` in modern browsers is considered to be a **bad practice** by many for a reason. If you want a method for better animations, read about the [**`window.requestAnimationFrame()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) function. I used `setInterval` here, because **animation is not the main subject of this question**.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(options) {
    Object.assign(this, 
      // the default options of the Circle constructor
      {      
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        diameter: 50,
        color: 'red'
      }, 
      // the options, that were passed and will be used to override the default options
      options
    );
  
    // the circle's move/update animation interval in ms (similar to FPS in games)
    this.updateInterval = 100;
  }

  draw() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.width = `${this.diameter}px`;
    div.style.height = `${this.diameter}px`;
    div.style.border = "1px solid;";
    div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    // store the reference to the div element for later use
    this.circle = div;
    // use the refacterd positioning function
    this._reposition();
  }

  move({x = 0, y = 0, duration = 1000}) {
    // store coordinates to use, when the circle will be moved
    this.initialX = this.x;
    this.initialY = this.y;
    this.destX = x,
    this.destY = y;
    
    // store the current time in ms
    this.startTime = Date.now();
    this.duration = duration
    
    // if a previous setInterval of this circle instance is still running, clear it (stop it)
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    // start the update (tick/ticker in games)
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this._update.bind(this), this.updateInterval);
  }
  
  _update() {
    // calculate the elapsed time
    const elapsed = Date.now() - this.startTime;    
    // calculate the progress according to the total given duration in percent
    let progress = elapsed / this.duration;
    // bound to [n..1]
    if (progress > 1) {
      progress = 1;
    }
    
    // set the x and y coordinates according to the progress...
    this.x = this.initialX + (this.destX * progress);
    this.y = this.initialY + (this.destY * progress);
    // ...and reposition the circle    
    this._reposition();
    console.log('update', this.x, this.y, progress);
    
    // stop the update, when the end is reached
    if (elapsed >= this.duration) {
      console.log('stopped', this.x, this.y, progress);
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
  }
  
  _reposition() {
    // set the position of the circle instance
    this.circle.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
    this.circle.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
  }
}

const options = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  diameter: 50,
  color: 'red'
};

const circle = new Circle(options);
circle.draw();
circle.move({x: 300, y: 50});
```